# CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present

Tags: typescript, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I'm getting this error message when I'm making a request on my servlet from my browser:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Into my server I've created this filter:

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter
{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException
    {   
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    }

}
```

And this is my typescript code:

```
var oHeaders = {
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json;odata.metadata=minimal',
      "Odata-Version": "4.0",
      "Odata-MaxVersion": "4.0",
      "Prefer": "odata.allow-entityreferences"
    };

    var metadataRequest =
    {
      headers: oHeaders,
      requestUri: "http://localhost:8080/olingo/odata/$metadata",
      data: null
    };

    this.odata$ = Observable.create(o =>
      oData.read(
        metadataRequest,
        (data, response) => {
          o.next({ data, response });
          o.complete();
        },
        (error) => o.error(error),
        null
      )
    );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `Origin` header in your request. Add this:

```
'Origin': 'http://example.com'
```

to your headers in your javascript. And I would try adding a content type header as well:

```
'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'    // For example
```

If none of that solves the problem, add the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` in the receiving PHP file manually at the top of the page like this:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```